# How to send binary data back to client using GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I have a GraphQL server, hosted on express. I want to return images to the client by sending back nodejs buffer objects. How can i config graphql server, to return bytes, instead of json? I don't wish to do this through base64, as the image are large in size.

Comment: Why not to simply return a URL string? Streaming files over GraphQL seem to be unnatural.

Comment: yep seems like it,  graphql can only return json.  I manage to resolve this, by creating another websocket channel(not using graphql), and emit my request arguments to the server.

Comment: I have the same problem, How you did it?

Answer (score 7):

You have to return JSON, but there's still a way.  We're using GraphQL to return images stored in Blob fields in a legacy sql database.  We're using sequelize, graphql-sequelize, and graphql-js.
We've defined the Blob fields to be String types in our graphql schema and so they come through in the json reply just fine.
Then we convert to a buffer before delivering, like

`const imgBuffer = new Buffer.from(imgObj.data, 'ascii');`

The only problem is we're now having trouble saving image data back to the database via the graphql interface.  Our mutation function gives us a syntax error when it finds certain bad unicode characters in the strings, like \U0000 and whatnot (so I found your question looking for a solution to that).

Comment: Converting binary data to ASCII isn't "converting to a buffer".

Comment: `Buffer.from(string[, encoding]) returns a new Buffer that contains a copy of the provided string.`  (from https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html  )

Answer (score 1):

There's a way, but it's complicated, and very manual, and I'm only going to give you an overview of what I've done in ApolloServer, but I think it should be enough.

First, you need to use the "Accept" header in your request to send a binary mime type, and send a matching "Content-Type" in your response. This is nessisary to be efficient, but not nessisary to work, as you'll see (with EJSON).

To serialize and deserialize respecting the headers you may need to write an express middleware, and you'll need to handle base64 encoding with a {$data: "..."} encapsulating object (as EJSON does) or just (strangely) returning null, if someone makes a request for binary data using "application/json" for their "accept" header. You'll also want to choose what binary formats that you'll support. I only use 1: "application/x-msgpack", but I hear that "application/cbor" is becoming more popular. You can use a library for EJSON, MessagePack, and CBOR to do your serialization, so this isn't as hard as it sounds.

I would then strongly recommend using the @defer on any images. See this post for more information on @defer: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/introducing-defer-in-apollo-server-f6797c4e9d6e/

I've done it. It wasn't easy, and it would be better if ApolloServer worked this way "out of the box".

Answer (score 1):

## It's better to send a hashed & temporary link to download it

- The URL can be hashed to be non-accessible by other users.
- Backend can expire the link or remove the binary file on the static server.

Answer (score -1):

There might be an answer to your question by using the node module found [here](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client).